# How to add, and remove HashMap values by insertion order?

Tags: java, hashmap, limit, wowza, linkedhashmap

I would like to know how I could map the users that connect based on their unique id's and id session so that when there are more than 3 sessions for that id, the users who connected first are removed from the hashmap and so on.

Example:

```
UserID:3 Session:1980002
UserID:3 Session:2841111
UserID:3 Session:84848
```

The UserID already contains 3 active sessions, the oldest one is removed and the KillSession invoked, giving way to new.

```
UserID:3 Session:2841111
UserID:3 Session:84848
UserID:3 Session:4848880
```

Code:

```
public void onHTTPCupertinoStreamingSessionCreate(HTTPStreamerSessionCupertino httpSession) {
    String User_Session = httpSession.getSessionId();
    String Client_ID = httpSession.getProperties().getPropertyStr("sql_client_id");
    /* Verifies that there are already 3 active sessions and removes the oldest, 
    since the limit of simultaneous sessions is 3 for each user,
    and add to hashmap, Client_ID and User_Session */
}

public void onHTTPCupertinoStreamingSessionDestroy(IHTTPStreamerSession httpSession) {
    String User_Session = httpSession.getSessionId();
    //remove from hashmap, Client_ID based on session User_Session
}

public void KillSession(int SessionId){ 
    IApplicationInstance Instance = applicationInstance;
    IHTTPStreamerSession sessions = Instance.getHTTPStreamerSessions().get(SessionId);
    sessions.rejectSession();
    //remove from hashmap, Client_ID based on session User_Session
}
```

The Client_ID is the id of the user in the database, the User_Session is the unique session in the wowza generated for each connection, this session does not have equal values, that is, if the same Client_ID connects more than once, that value will be different For each of your sessions.

That is, basically my difficulty is to mount the hashmap, how could I do this?

Comment: I don’t understand. Is the user id the key of your map (whether a `HashMap` or some other type)? If so, I suggest an `ArrayDeque<Session>` as value of the map. If the `ArrayDeque` already has size 3, take out the first session and kill it, then add the new session at the end. You can just use `Queue<Session>` for the map value type, but `ArrayDeque<Session>` for the actual instances.

Comment: A `HashMap<String, String>` or `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` cannot map from one user ID to three session IDs. It can only hold each key once and with only one value for that key.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add and remove in insertion order, use a LinkedHashMap. 
(A simple version of what might be of help)

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LinkedHashMapExample {
    static class User {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> sessionIds = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        int userId;

        public User(int userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public void addSession(String someField, int sessionId) {
            this.sessionIds = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>(sessionIds) {
                protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<String, Integer> eldest) {
                    return size() > 3;
                }
            };
            sessionIds.put(someField, sessionId);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User{" +
                    "sessionIds=" + sessionIds +
                    ", userId=" + userId +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user1 = new User(1);
        user1.addSession("1980002", 1980002);
        user1.addSession("84848", 84848);
        user1.addSession("2841111", 2841111);
        System.out.println(user1);
        user1.addSession("999999", 999999);
        System.out.println(user1);
        user1.addSession("777777", 777777);
        System.out.println(user1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not know much about HashMap, could you give me an example of how I could do this? This is my difficulty, use the hashmap and compute how many sessions are active for the same UserID, if more than 3, do as in the example I put.

Comment: Hi Florida, Can you provide the key,value structure of your map ?

Comment: I have nothing ready to map, but the values K, V can be in `String` or `int`.

Comment: Hi, i have updated my answer with a simple example of how you can use LinkedHashMap.

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration. You’re creating a new `LinkedHashMap` instance for each new session ID, that’s a waste. And you are not using it for mapping from one kind of thing to another, rather as a set, it seems (which isn’t needed here since duplicate session IDs don’t occur for the same user anyway). The overriding of `removeEldestEntry()` is elegant. You may want to add an `@Override` annotation.

Comment: Well, optimizations are possible. You can even solve it using a Queue or a Vector, if the problem is understood more (from the entire code base perspective). The code i shared was only a demonstration of how LinkedHashMap can be used.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly that you want to store up to three session IDs per user/client ID, I don’t really think that a `LinkedHashMap` will help you. It is correct that a `LinkedHashMap` maintains insertion order, as opposed to a `HashMap`.

I have a different suggestion for you. To keep things separate, I suggest this little auxiliary class to hold the map:

```
public class MapOfSessions {

    private Map<String, Queue<Integer>> sessionMap = new HashMap<>();

    public int countSessions(String clientId) {
        Queue<Integer> q = sessionMap.get(clientId);
        if (q == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return q.size();
        }
    }

    public int removeOldestSession(String clientId) {
        return sessionMap.get(clientId).remove();
    }

    public void add(String clientId, int sessionId) {
        Queue<Integer> q = sessionMap.get(clientId);
        if (q == null) {
            q = new ArrayDeque<>();
            sessionMap.put(clientId, q);
        }
        q.add(sessionId);
    }

    public void remove(String clientId, int sessionId) {
        sessionMap.get(clientId).remove(sessionId);
        // if queue is now empty, may remove key from map
    }
}
```

Now the map is what keeps the correspondenace between client ID and session ID, while the `Queue` is keeping the insertion order.

With this you may solve your task in the following way. I have taken the removal from the map out of `killSession()` and have given that responibility to the caller, `onHTTPCupertinoStreamingSessionCreate()`.

```
private int maxSessionsPerUser = 3;
private MapOfSessions sessionsPerUser = new MapOfSessions();

public void onHTTPCupertinoStreamingSessionCreate(HTTPStreamerSessionCupertino httpSession) {
    // use camel case for variable names: begin with lowercase, no underscores
    String userSession = httpSession.getSessionId();
    String clientId = httpSession.getProperties().getPropertyStr("sql_client_id");
    /* Verifies that there are already 3 active sessions and removes the oldest, 
    since the limit of simultaneous sessions is 3 for each user,
    and add to hashmap, clientId and userSession */
    if (sessionsPerUser.countSessions(clientId) == maxSessionsPerUser) {
        int oldestSession = sessionsPerUser.removeOldestSession(clientId);
        killSession(oldestSession);
    }
    sessionsPerUser.add(clientId, Integer.parseInt(userSession));
}

public void onHTTPCupertinoStreamingSessionDestroy(IHTTPStreamerSession httpSession) {
    String userSession = httpSession.getSessionId();
    // it’s easier to remove from map when we know both clientId and userSession
    String clientId = httpSession.getProperties().getPropertyStr("sql_client_id");
    //remove from hashmap, clientId based on session userSession
    sessionsPerUser.remove(clientId, Integer.parseInt(userSession));
}

// method name in camel case (like variable names)
public void killSession(int SessionId){ 
    IApplicationInstance Instance = applicationInstance;
    IHTTPStreamerSession sessions = Instance.getHTTPStreamerSessions().get(SessionId);
    sessions.rejectSession();
    //don’t remove from hashmap here, assume caller has done that
}
```

I am storing the client ID as string and the session ID as integer. You may want to use the same type for both. Since you had declared `KillSession()`with an `int` parameter, I thought I’d use `int` for the session.